# Error when using + in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a code jquery

```
$font = 5;
$font_test = $font + 1;
alert($font_test);
```

When I run code is result is 51, But result exactly is 6, How to fix it in jquery ?

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Q7u29/...the anwser is 6....explain other parameters that are in the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

```
$font = 5;
$font_test = parseInt($font) + 1;
alert($font_test);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UfxsC/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [jsfiddle.net/Q7u29/](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7u29/)...the anwser is 6....explain other parameters that are in the rest of the code

if font is `$font = "5";` i.e a string then the answer is 51..use `parseInt($font)`